# How to load data from Google compute engine to cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm new to Google Cloud Platform. I downloaded some `*.csv` files to Google Compute Engine (GCE) and did some transformations and saved the files in the storage linked to GCE.  I found that I can install MySQL in GCE and load the data in there. But I want to load data to MySQL in Google Cloud SQL (GCS). Is there any way to load data from GCE to GCS.

TIA

Comment: According to what you say your data is stored as `*.CSV` files in a Compute Engine instance right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a guide on how to import CSV files into Cloud SQL instances. Just make sure the data you have fulfils the [requirements](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/#csv_file_reqs).

In brief, you have to perform these steps:

1. Create a storage bucket and upload your files there.
2. Go to the console and there, go to the Cloud SQL instances page.
3. Click the import button:

[image]

4. Under Format, select `CSV`. Specify the Database and Table in your Cloud SQL instance where you wish to import the `CSV` file:

[image]

5. Click the **Import** to start the import.

The more detailed guide is [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing#importing_csv_files).

Comment: Thank you Victor. I followed the same process as you have mentioned. This didn't work for postgres due to permission issues on the test tables that I have created. But when I switched to mysql, it worked.

Comment: One more step in the process before importing data is to create database into which you want to import the data if you didn't create one.